# Method converting a dictionary stored in a Pandas DataFrame column into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have time-series data in a HDF file. When I load this file I get a `Pandas DataFrame` like this:

```
DateTimeIndex | col 1 (float) | ... | col N (float) | dict_col (dict)
```

The `dictionary` in `dict_col` contains data structured like a normal dictionary:

```
{'field1': value1 (float), ..., 'fieldN': valueN (float)}
```

How can I convert the initial `DataFrame` in a `DataFrame` structured like this?:

```
DateTimeIndex | col 1 (float) | ... | col N (float) | field1 (float) | ... | floatN (float)
```

Currently, my code looks lie this:

```
data = DataFrame(pd.read_hdf('the_hdf_file.h5'))

out_frame = DataFrame() # output DataFrame

for column in data.columns:
    if column != 'dict_col':
        out_frame = pd.concat([out_frame, data[column]], axis=1)
    else:
        sub_set = data[column]
        for value in sub_set.items():
            item_series = Series(value[0])
            item_series = item_series.rename({0: 'time'})
            item_series = pd.concat([item_series, Series(value[1])])
            out_frame = pd.concat([out_frame, item_series], axis=1)

... manipulations with out_frame ...
```

But this code is utterly slow. How can I do this in a more efficient way?

EDIT: provided [Test Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2ekUU_XRnxgVfgc2hVA8PfLsWjTqb8Y/view?usp=sharing). Note that 'dict_col' is called 'rawdata_boxfit' in the test data.

Comment: Can you provide (dummy) `data` for reproducibility? You can add the output from `print(data.to_csv(index=False))` to your question.

Comment: Data is available on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2ekUU_XRnxgVfgc2hVA8PfLsWjTqb8Y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_hdf('test_data_20220720.h5'))
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data.rawdata_boxfit)
```

[image]

To merge new columns use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_hdf('test_data_20220720.h5'))
new = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data.rawdata_boxfit)
new.index = data.index
pd.concat([data, new], axis=1).drop('rawdata_boxfit', axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  I used to do....   df.dict_col.apply(pd.Series)  But I think this is better

Comment: Works like a fly! thx